# Can't install Java\JDK on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, java, windows-installation

I've installed Windows 10 x64 from official page and now can't install Java or JDK. When I try to execute a file nothing happen. I tried 8u66 x64\x32 and 8u65 x64\x32. Need it for work so it's very important for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved.** There are two solution when one of them or both solve the issue:

1. Reinstall Windows 10 from ISO.
2. Have a working built-in administrator account (There should be no UAC shields if you are right clicking on C:\Program Files). First point also helps to get working account.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps helped me with the same problem:

1. Enable Administrator account. Open CMD, or PowerShell terminal and run command:

> net user administrator /active:yes

2. Setup password
3. Change account type for current user to: Standard
4. Reboot system

I'm not sure that second step is necessary.