# installer for java dev. kit (jdk-8u102-windows-x64) FREEZES on progress bar

Tags: windows-10, java, freeze, uac

I saw multiple threads regarding this issue, and no solution has worked out for me. <[Can't install Java\JDK on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1020058/cant-install-java-jdk-on-windows-10)>, <[JDK 8 installation does not progress on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1100808/jdk-8-installation-does-not-progress-on-windows-10)>

I have downloaded the official Oracle exe windows installer for 64 bit system, and tried to install it. After the initial extraction is complete, the "status" progress bar freezes and I can't find any solution:

1. I run it as administrator.
2. I activated the hidden windows 10 admin account, and ran it as administrator once again.
3. I disactivated the UAC in windows control panel.
4. I formatted my windows 10 OS completely.

I really ran out of options, and this is the most frustrating thing ever. Please help me.

Here is OK:

[image]

Here is the FREEZE progress bar:

[image]

Few Notes:

- I didn't have these issues with any other software I tried to install
- I installed successfully the java-7 latest public release.

Comment: Your hard drive isn't full, is it?

Comment: Not at all. It is almost empty for the matter of fact, the OS was completely formatted.

Comment: Hmm.. have you tried installing in safe mode?

Comment: @jatuttle0 thank you very much, I didn't try it and it worked. Also I noticed, that the jdk was actually installed, and the extra step that was stucked was just the "close" button with "success" message.

Comment: @Mike: You can answer your own questions and accept it as the answer that worked, or make up for @ jatuttle0,  this gives the site a working answer for this question should anybody have the same problem, you can also add more detail to the question giving a broader base for searches of similar questions, thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jatuttle0 suggested, installing the jdk from safe mode did the trick. Also, I think that if all the files were extracted to C:/Java/jdk... then you shouldn't be worried too much for this freezing progress bar since it doesn't do anything accept saying that the installation was successfull.

Answer (score 0):

First install the JRE before installing the SDK.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it's works for me.

1. Run Command Prompt as Administrator.
2. Then, run the JDK installation file (.exe) in Command Prompt

Gook Luck!

Comment: Welcome to superuser: not everybody would understand now to install or run the file from cmd. Could you expand your answer as this answer has been accepted and this is a 'you could also try it this way'. You may have already read [help] or [answer] so anyway again welcome to superuser.